# How to gain access to changing target branch of PR in TFS

Tags: git, tfs

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-141-update#change-the-target-branch-of-a-pull-request), it should be easy to change the target branch of my PR. However, no such pencil appears for me. What permission do I need for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article you reference describes the functionality of Azure DevOps. As far as I understand, you're using TFS, that is, the on-prem version. The functionality to change the target branch in pull request arrived at Azure DevOps with [Sprint 141 completion on October 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-141-update), however, it was not released as a part of any TFS update yet.

If you navigate to this link, and scroll down to `October 1 2018` section, you'll the value `2019` in the top right column. It means that the mentioned changes will be merged and released in the scope of Azure DevOps Server (formerly known as TFS) in 2019 version:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the pencil icon. Do we need to have a special permission to see the Pencil icon?

Thanks, Praveen

Comment: Alright, the pencil is removed now. Now there is a new Context menu there with the name "Change Target Branch". It shows up when you click on the  vertical "...".

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple to just abandon that Pull Request and create a new one with right destination branch